# Payload was not valid JSON Slack Webhooks PHP

Tags: php, json, slack

Slack Incoming Webhooks returns Payload was not valid JSON and the documentation doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense.

```
public function index() {

    $message = [
        "pretext"    => "There's been a sale on Example Cart",
        "title"      => "Sales Order #123456 on Example Cart",
        "title_link" => "http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?route=sale/order/info&order_id=123456",
        "text"       => "There's been a new sale on the Example website. Click the order above to check it out.",
    ];

    $send = self::slack($message);

    dd($send); // die and dump curl result

}

public static function slack($message, $room = "test-messages", $color = "#ED7100", $icon = ":mailbox:") {

    foreach ($message as $key => $value):
        $message[$key] = str_replace(["<", ">", "&"], ["&lt;", "&gt;", "&amp;"], $value);
    endforeach;

    $fallback = $message["pretext"] . " - " . $message["title"] . " - " . $message["title_link"];

    $attachments = [
        "fallback"   => $fallback,
        "pretext"    => $message["pretext"],
        "title"      => $message["title"],
        "title_link" => $message["title_link"],
        "text"       => $message["text"],
        "color"      => $color,
    ];

    $payload = [
        "channel"     => "#{$room}",
        "channel"     => "@bossman",
        "icon_emoji"  => $icon,
        "username"    => "webhook-tests",
        "attachments" => [$attachments]
    ];

    $data = "payload=" . json_encode($payload);

    $ch = curl_init("https://hooks.slack.com/services/endpoint");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

When I lint the JSON in any of the online linters it returns as valid JSON.

What is Slack looking for that's not in the documentation?

Comment: Have a look at [this gist example](https://gist.github.com/pugwonk/f2cdd9d83d964627c335) - it looks like they are using passing the payload a little differently.

Comment: That's where I got this, I'm trying to modify it to add attachments. I need to pass rich text messages not just plain text.

Comment: I was looking at this line: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => $data));`

Comment: I wonder how the heck I ended up with that ... weird, I copied that exact gist. Anyway thanks John, post this as an answer so I can accept it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your POST data is being sent with `payload=` at the front instead of as the key.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/pugwonk/f2cdd9d83d964627c335) sends the data like so:

```
$data = json_encode($payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => $data));
```

Comment: Also that `foreach` loop can be removed as it seems `json_encode` takes care of escaping.